# Cross browser OGG audio

Tags: html, audio, cross-browser, ogg

I have to play an ogg audio file in the background when the user hits a "Music On" button. Currently the page uses an AUDIO tag, and it works in Firefox, but not in IE (confirmed by   [this table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)).

Is there a really cross-browser way to play an ogg audio file, if possible without Flash?

I am aware of the existence of specific libraries like JPlayer or SoundManager, but do I really have to use one of them? After all, it is just to play a sound...

Comment: Most browsers can play mp3s. Are you locked into ogg?

Comment: My question is specifically about OGG audio, not mp3, wav or whatever else...

Comment: Link is broken, should be: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp  (I can't edit original post)

Comment: @David Thanks, I've just fixed it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forget about cross-browser.  Stick with ogg.  It's much better than mp3 in every way.  Tell people to change their browser to one which supports ogg (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Opera).  If they don't want to change, then forget about them; they don't deserve to hear your audio.  If your client doesn't understand this, leave him and let him waste money on one developer after another until he finds a "yes man" developer who will give him a terrible website that will be a nightmare to use and will need completely redeveloped in a year's time.

Answer (score 2):

The Company I work for has dropped support for IE6 for apps and websites and dropped support for IE7 when it comes to apps. Personally, I don't want to be developing for IE at all until I met a friend of mine working elsewhere. She was allowed to work from home, but she had to use RDP (Remote Desktop Connection in Windows) thats  supported as a web interface only via IE. Some companies use Windows Group policies to disable USB drives etc. The terminals in these companies can have IE only! So as much as I would hate to admit, cross browser compatibility is a serious issue.

Flash would be the number one choice of plugin to play ogg files. Now, the following scenarios may occur:

1. iOS (iPad and iPhone) : HTML5 Audio Tag
2. Android / Chrome / Safari : HTML5 Audio Tag
3. Opera
4. Firefox
5. IE

For 3, 4 and 5 it really depends on the user. Even if they have one of Real Player, QuickTime or Windows Media Player, the would be able to play ogg files. There is a case where the specific ogg codec is not installed. In this case they will get a prompt on the top of their browser, telling them to install the specific codec.

We are  talking about people insisting on using IE or insisting on a really really old version of firefox and who don't have WMP (by default on Windows), RealPlayer or QuickTIme installed but have an Internet connection.

*Even jQuery leaves out 0.0001% of users ! :-P*

Answer (score 0):

You can probably consider using a `.wav` file, but I'm not sure that works.

The simple answer: no, there's no way to do it without Flash. My approach: simply create a script that converts a single file to multiple encodings.

Comment: It would be nice if I could do so, but this ogg file is provided by the client.

Comment: It's not that hard to write a script on the server that converts to other file formats.

Comment: Sure, but that is not my server... The client wants this file to be played on his page. I have his html and js code, but I do not have access to the server.

Comment: Then, as they often say, "you're screwed" ;-)

Comment: .wav doesn't work in IE9+ according to this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp